# Get SOAP request as XML in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, soap

I need to get the XML Soap request coming to a url on my server. I wrote something like

```
@RequestMapping("/SomeService")
@ResponseBody
public String index(@RequestBody String request) {
    mailService.sendMail("someone@gmail.com", "Subject", request);
    return "";
}
```

But the request body is coming as blank. I'm using spring 3.2. I just need the XML SOAP content. How do I proceed in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your spring configuration xml ?

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest a few ways of doing this @Akhil:

1. If you want to expose a robust SOAP based endpoint, then the best approach would be to use one of the full-fledged JAX-WS implementations(say Apache CXF or Axis2).
2. If you want to be a little more lightweight and want to be completely under the Spring umbrella of projects, I would highly recommend using Spring-WS as the endpoint to consume the SOAP request and serve out a response - Spring WS is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/index.html): http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/index.html
3. If this is an ad-hoc endpoint that you are using not for real business reasons but say just for capturing info and do not really care for other features that SOAP brings - say security, validation etc, marshalling, unmarshalling support etc, then an option would be to use Spring's [HttpRequestHandlingServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/HttpRequestHandlerServlet.html), this way you can implement a HttpRequestHandler which takes HttpServletRequest as a parameter and grab the POSTed content from it.

These as you have probably noted is all outside of Spring MVC, the reason is the framework tends to consume the raw http request and provides the parameters once it has pre-processed them, so even if you write a @RequestMapped method expecting a raw string, you will not get it cleanly.

Comment: thanks. that means since I have few Spring MVC controllers, I won't be able to implement this or can I use it for just one controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. I think you have to define this method as a POST. And define the headers as well. It will support to define this as GET but in the server side it will not identify the Body contents in the @RequestBody .

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/SomeService", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index(@RequestBody String request) {
        mailService.sendMail("someone@gmail.com", "Subject", request);
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following bean definition in your beans definition file. My bean definition has beans prefix.

```
<beans:bean name="handlerAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
        </util:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: next step? will this convert incoming request.

Comment: You will get the complete SOAP request as String. Use the SAAJ library to parse the string and get it as SOAPMessage, else write your own SOAPHTTPMessageConverter to do the task based on content-type.